# how to find MAX memory from docker stats?

Tags: docker

With `docker stats` you can see the memory usage of a container over time.

Is there a way to find what the highest value of memory usage was while running `docker stats`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a sampling script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42810377/671880) and aggregated data by @pl_rock. But be careful - the `sort` command only compares string values - so the results are usually wrong (but ok for me).
Also mind that docker is sometimes reporting wrong numbers (ie. more allocated mem than physical RAM).

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

"$@" & # Run the given command line in the background.
pid=$!

echo "" > stats

while true; do
  sleep 1
  sample="$(ps -o rss= $pid 2> /dev/null)" || break

  docker stats --no-stream --format "{{.MemUsage}} {{.Name}} {{.Container}}" | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0 }' >> stats
done

for containerid in `awk '/.+/ { print $7 }' stats | sort | uniq`
do
    grep "$containerid" stats | sort -r -k3 | tail -n 1
    # maybe: | sort -r -k3 -h | head -n 1
    # see comment below (didnt tested)
done
```

Comment: this is awesome

Comment: the line in the last cycle should be:

`grep "$containerid" stats | sort -r -k3 -h | head -n 1`


  1. head, not tail, if you want maximum
  2. -h for sort command gives it an idea that it's some human-readable format and it interprets the docker output fine now, e.g. "426MiB" (should, however, test against strings comparison, maybe it was all just luck)

Comment: You can use `sort -n` for a numeric sort.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to find the peak usage you are better off requesting the `.MemPerc` option and calculating based on the total memory (unless you restricted the memory available to the container).  `.MemUsage` has units which change during the life of the container which mess with the result.

```
docker stats --format 'CPU: {{.CPUPerc}}\tMEM: {{.MemPerc}}'
```

You can stream an ongoing log to a file (or script).

To get just the max memory as originally requested:

```
(timeout 120 docker stats --format '{{.MemPerc}}' <CONTAINER_ID> \
  | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g' ; echo) \
  | tr -d '%' | sort -k1,1n | tail -n 1
```

And then you can ask the system for its total RAM (again assuming you didn't limit the RAM available to docker) and calculate:

```
awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo
```

You would need to know how long the container is going to run when using timeout as above, but if `docker stats` was run without this in background submitted by a script it could kill it once the container completed.

...

This command allows you to generate a time-series of the cpu/memory load:

```
(timeout 20 docker stats --format \
  'CPU: {{.CPUPerc}}\tMEM: {{.MemPerc}}' <CONTAINER_ID> \
  | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g' ; echo) \
  | gzip -c > monitor.log.gz
```

Note that it pipes into gzip.  In this form you get ~2 rows per second so the file would get large rapidly if you don't.

I'd advise this for benchmarking and trouble shooting rather than use on production containers

Answer (score 6):

In my case I wanted to monitor a docker container which runs tests for my web application. The test suite is pretty big, it includes javascript tests in a real browser and consume significant amount of both, memory and time.

Ideally, I wanted to watch the current memory usage real time, but to also keep the history for later analysis.

I ended up using a modified and simplified version of the [Keiran's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49519845/786948):

```bash
CONTAINER=$(docker ps -q -f name=CONTAINER_NAME)
FORMAT='{{.MemPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}\t{{.Name}}'

docker stats --format $FORMAT $CONTAINER | sed -u 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g' | tee stats
```

Notes:

- `CONTAINER=$(docker ps -q -f name=NAME)` find container by name, but there are [other options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering)
- `FORMAT='{{.MemPerc}} ...}}` MemPerc goes first (for sorting); otherwise you can be [creative](https://blog.container-solutions.com/docker-inspect-template-magic)
- `sed -u` the `-u` flag is important, it turns off buffering
- `| sed -u 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g'` removes ANSI escape sequences
- `| tee stats` not only display in real time, but also write into the `stats` file
- I Ctrl-C manually when it's ready – not ideal, but OK for me
- after that it's easy to find the max with something like `sort -n stats | tail`

Answer (score 2):

you can use command:

```
docker stats --no-stream | awk '{ print $3 }' | sed '1d'|sort | tail -1
```

It will give highest memory by container.

Let me Explain command:

```
 --no-stream :          Disable streaming stats and only pull the first result
 awk '{ print $3 }' :   will print MEM USAGE
 sed '1d' :             will delete first entry that is %
 sort :                 it will sort the result
 tail -1 :              it will give last entry that is highest.
```

Comment: I think this will tell you the current value of whatever container is using the most memory with an instantaneous check. My reading of the question is they are looking for the highest memory of all containers during the time they have had docker stats running (non-instantaneous).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  I would like to run docker stats against a single container for an extended period of time and figure out the maximum memory it used during that time. Maybe something like "watch "docker stats CONTAINER --no-stream | ????".